# npm audit complains about vulnerability after I upgraded package

Tags: node.js, npm, underscore.js

I installed an npm package called `bbfy@0.1.0` and in part of the output npm says:

```
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

So I run `npm audit fix` but it says it can't fix it:

```
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 202 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

So I run npm audit and I get this message:

```
$ npm audit

                       === npm audit security report ===


                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  High            Arbitrary Code Execution

  Package         underscore

  Patched in      >=1.12.1

  Dependency of   bbfy

  Path            bbfy > underscore

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1674

found 1 high severity vulnerability in 202 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

So I go to the webpage referenced, and it tells me to upgrade `underscore` to "versions 1.12.1 or 1.13.0-2 or later", so I run this command:

```
$ npm i underscore@1.13.0-2
[snip]
+ underscore@1.13.0-2
updated 1 package and audited 202 packages in 2.726s
[snip]
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Still complaining about 1 vulnerability though. I checked with `npm audit` and its the same underscore vulnerability. So did I fix the problem or not? If I didn't, what went wrong?

Comment: My solution (which isn't a real one, that's why I comment) is just to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

NPM will install multiple copies of a package to satisfy conflicting version requirements in the packages that depend on it (including your own project at the top level).

An older, vulnerable version of `underscore` is installed because the `bbfy` package depends on that older version. What your `npm i` command did was to install another separate copy of `underscore` at the later version you requested. (You can remove that one, unless you'll be using `underscore` directly in your project.)

Since `bbfy` hasn't been updated in five years, the only way to work around this will be to override the dependency with [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-shrinkwrap). (This might produce broken code, but I doubt `underscore` has changed in any problematic way from 1.8 to 1.12.)